# Correctly quoting stored procedure parameter for value in where clause

Tags: mysql

Consider the following stored procedure and its usage:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ShowMIHoles;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowMIHoles(IN CourseID VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    select * from tblcourses where id=CourseID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;


call ShowMIHoles(1299)
```

That works, and returns the row of table tblcourses with id 1299.
However, it isn't protected from SQL injection.
So, I read that `quote()` should be used to make a value safe.

This is my attempt to use quote:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ShowMIHoles;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowMIHoles(IN CourseID VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    select * from tblcourses where id=quote(CourseID);
END $$
DELIMITER ;

call ShowMIHoles(1299)
```

That results in "0 rows returned". No error message. MySQL 5.7.28.

I tried various tests to see what was going wrong. The ones that don't use `CourseID` parameter, I tested both inside procedure, and as a stand-alone query.

```
select quote(1299);
```

=> '1299'

```
select * from tblcourses where id='1299';
```

=> The expected row with id 1299.

```
select * from tblcourses where id=quote(1299);
```

=> 0 rows returned.

It is possible to make this work, via prepared statement:

```
...
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('select * from tblcourses where id=', quote(CourseID));
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
END $$
...
```

=> The expected row with id 1299.

**Question:**

Is there any way to safely use this parameter as an expression value in the where clause, without dynamically preparing a statement?

Comment: I just realized that CourseID should be an integer, to match the table column. Ran tests again with `CREATE PROCEDURE ShowMIHoles(IN CourseID INTEGER)`. Same results. In hindsight, that had to be the same, since using literal `=quote(1299)` didn't work.

Comment: MySQL QUOTE() produces a string   so if you need  an Integer this can produce problems.. you shoulld use quote only when you have string

Comment: @scaisEdge - ok, that helps explain. But is `where id=CourseId` safe from injection, if I specify integer parameter?  Integer parameter forces it to be an integer before it does anything? If it is safe, then that is the answer: declare INTEGER, don't quote. Would you like to post as answer?  Otherwise, I will.

Comment: For tne INT da data type and sqlinjecttion you should only check if  the content is just an INT  .. if the value is ONLY a proper  INT this mean that this value don't contain any text and then can produce sqlinjection  ( injection of mailciuou SQL code that tiplically is a text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to worry about SQL injection inside a stored procedure unless you are using dynamic SQL. Strings will always be treated like whole string and numbers as numbers.

So, the first version you are showing is perfectly fine. Just make sure that when you call the procedure, your code is safe.

Comment: *"Just make sure that when you call the procedure, your code is safe."* Yes, but I see recommendations that when writing a stored procedure, it is wise to write it in such a way that if it is called poorly (with inputs from users), it is safe. In my particular case, the way to make it safest is to change the parameter type to `INTEGER`; then there is nowhere that a user input string might get injected to change the expected behaviour of the query. Right?

Comment: *"Strings will always be treated like whole string"* - ahh, that is what I didn't grasp. So a procedure parameter is inherently protected from injection; even if I had been comparing strings, `.. where MyStringField=MyStringParam` would be compiled in such a way that `MyStringParam` is simply a string; it couldn't alter the *structure* of the query?

Comment: Yes, as said, you are safe unless a) you use dynamic SQL b) your procedure call itself is compromised. With integer parameter and making sure you pass in an integer, you are safe.